# How to extend generic classes?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to make a class extend another class among several like this:

```
class Special extends < Class1<type1> , Class2<Type2>> {
  // ToDo
}
```

I tried something like:

```
 class Special<T1, T2, T3, T4> extends < T1<T2> , T3<T4>> {
      // ToDo
    }
```

Of course that syntax does not compile. How can I do that?

---

EDIT 1

Let's be clear here: I do NOT want multiple inheritance. I would like my class to extend EITHER one super class, EITHER another one. For that I am asking if there is a possibility doing so using generics.

The same way one can use generics for this special map of array:

```
class MapArray<T_KEY, T_VALUE> extends LinkedHashMap<T_KEY, ArrayList<T_VALUE>> {

}
```

This code works an allows the user to put any type for T_KEY and T_VALUE.
I would like to know whether is would be possible to use generics with classes.

To put it more simply I would like to do that:

```
class Special extends < Either_this_class, Either_this_one > {

}
```

Comment: A class can only extend one super-class...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one class extend two classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587621/can-one-class-extend-two-classes)

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance; that is, a subclass can only have one parent class.

Comment: This doesn't sound like multiple inheritance.

Comment: the only thing I can think about is something like: `class Special<T1, T2, T3, T4> extends T<T1<T2>, T3<T4>>`

Comment: @Barranka I have read about multiple type parameters when it comes to generics (eg: hashmaps), but what does that do? When I look at it, it looks like incompatible types.

Comment: @Barranka I'd like to see an example you can compile.

Comment: Why the negative vote? There is no duplicate here It seems you misunderstod me. I don't want to extend several classes. I would like to my class to extend EITHER one super class, EITHER another. For that I am asking if there is a possibility doing so with using generics.

Comment: This is not possible. A class cannot have a different superclass depending on a type parameter. A class has exactly one superclass and it is always the same, regardless of any other parameter or whatnot that is in scope for the class.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt SImple and concise comment thanks. COuld you please write it as an answer so that i can mark this thread as solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can do (staying withing the limits of Java's syntax):

```
class SubAndImp extends Super implements Interface {
}
```

or

```
class ImpAndImp implements InterOne, InterTwo {
}
```

All or some of the extended and implemented types can be generic:

```
class SubAndImp<X,Y> extends Super<X> implements Interface<Y> {
}
```

or

```
class ImpAndImp<X,Y> implements InterOne<X>, InterTwo<Y> {
}
```

Your subclass can also stay out of being generic, by instantiating a generic parameter:

```
class SubAndImp extends Super<Integer> implements Interface<String> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java supports only multiple interface inheritance. So you cannot extend multiple classes but you can implement any number of interfaces.