# Can I use implements and extends at the same time?

Tags: java, android

Can i use the implements and the extends at the same time? Because I need to inherit something on the other class while i used implements on the same class.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implementsView.OnClickListener "extends ListActivity"
```

How can it be like that?

Comment: Yes. you can happily do it.

Comment: Can I inherit multiple classes? @MehrajMalik

Comment: Read this http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/multiple-inheritance/

Comment: @Jeyjey Multiple inheritance is not allowed in java.
 read this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587621/can-one-class-extend-two-classes

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. This isn't asking what they are defined as, it's specifically asking if you can do **both at the same time**. Which was my question and the linked answer did not answer that or give an example. Below Bathsheba does.

Answer (score 63):

Yes, you can. But you need to declare `extends` *before* `implements`:

```java
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Interface1, Interface2 {
 // ...
}
```

Any number of interfaces can be implemented, if more than one then each needs to be separated with a comma.

Comment: Can I inherit more than one class? @Bathsheba

Comment: No Java does not allow that.

Answer (score 14):

You can only extend **one class** but you implements **multiple interfaces** as your need.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Human extends Monkey implements BasicAnimals, xyz
```

in this way you can extend a class as well as implement interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can able to declare extends and implements together. But one condition you have to declare `extends` before `implements` keyword.

example

```
public class Dog extends Animal implements Interface1,Interface2
{
         //you should implement all methods here...
}
```