# Why define a abstract interface in Java

Tags: java

As we know, interface is to define some method, but some interface defined as a `abstract` interface, but why ?
for example:

```
public abstract interface Test{

}
```

what is the advantage for using `abstract` to define a interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to add that `abstract` key word. It's redundant there.

Interfaces are implicitly `abstract`.

[Language Spec JLS# 9.1.1.1 abstract Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1)

> Every interface is implicitly abstract.
>
> This modifier is obsolete and should not be used in new programs.

Answer (score 0):

refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html for the same.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778307/805378 to get the difference between abstract and interface.

Answer (score -1):

to make a class 100% abstract without using 'abstract'.