# Do Spring @Component classes have to be public?

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to expose a component's interface as an interface and the implementing class would be package protected (and maybe in some other package):

```
package baz.iface

interface Foo {
    void bar();
}  


package baz.whatever

@Component
class SpringyFoo implements baz.iface.Foo {
    public void bar() { frobnicate(); }
}
```

Assuming `baz.whatever` is in the `component-scan`, will Spring be able to autowire a `baz.iface.Foo` somewhere else?

```
class FooClient {
    @Autowired
    private baz.iface.Foo;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I just noticed another issue with this code: `baz.iface.Foo` isn't visible in `baz.whatever`. You'll need to make the interface `public`.

Answer (score 15):

No, components don't have to be public. The only requirement is that they have a no-arg constructor.

Comment: you can also use arguments in constructors for constructor injection: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Spring will search for objects of type `Foo`.
`SpringyFoo` implements `Foo` and can be used in place of object of type `Foo`.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that **no**, components **do not** have to be public.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make your `bar()` "package-protected" because it has to be `public`:

> [Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4)

Spring's reflection system will find all of your classes, even ones with default access, but it's a compile-time error for your `bar()` method not to be `public`.

Comment: That is probably a typo in `SpringyFoo`. Also you don't have to declare interface methods to be `public` as [they are always public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376970/protected-in-interfaces).

Comment: This question is poorly written and asks two diametrically opposed questions. I'm restating.

Comment: Well the real issue is that he should just try it. With Java Reflection / Byte code manipulation and a corresponding loose security manager you can do just about anything including even setting final fields.

Comment: yes, the missing `public` before `bar()` was a typo in `SpringyFoo`. I've updated the question.

I did try it and it seemed to work. However, all the docs/examples I could find always used public classes, so I wanted to know if this was supported behaviour.

Comment: I'm editing your question; let me know if it's not what you meant.