# I can not override methods from Externalizable due to strange weaker access modifier error in java

Tags: java, externalizable

In [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Externalizable.html) says that readExternal() and writeExternal() have default access modifier and I also implement it with default access modifier, but somehow I have 2 error which says that I assign weaker access modifier? So why is that? (I know that using default modifier I can not serializa/deserialize objects from other package)

Error1:

> Error:(19, 10) java: readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput) in A cannot
> implement readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput) in java.io.Externalizable
> attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Error2:

> Error:(16, 10) java: writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput) in A cannot
> implement writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput) in
> java.io.Externalizable   attempting to assign weaker access
> privileges; was public

```
class A implements Externalizable
{
    public A() {}
    
    @Override
    void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {}
    
    @Override
    void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {}
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you have to declare methods as public? The main point is when you implement/extend some interface/class you have to use at least the same access modifier or wider.

Comment: But I used the same access modifier: I have package-private and in documentation also package-private

Comment: Interface methods are always public.  See  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4, in particular, "Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`".  The `public` modifier is omitted from the documentation of interface methods because it is redundant.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you are right, maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: This question is quite probably a duplicate of some other questions on StackOverflow, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376970/protected-in-interfaces .