# How can I provided two interfaces (a "public" and and "extended" one) at the same time?

Tags: java, oop

I have blocks performing calculations using a function `step()`. The blocks can be connected to
each other with `connect(Block)`.

```
interface Block {
    void connect(Block b);
    void step();
}
```

However from within a concrete block implementation (e.g. in `step`) it should be
possible to `read` from the connected block:

```
class ABlockImpl implements Block {
    private Block src; // link to the block this block is connected to
    public void connect(Block b) {
        src = b;
    }

    public void step() {
        double x = src.read(); // XXX src is of type Block and there is no read() in Block
        /* ... */
    }

    public double read() {
        return 3.14;
    }
}
```

Since there is no `read()` in `Block`, this won't compile. For clients the "public" Block interface is sufficient, I need `read` only internally. I could add `read` to the Block interface, but to me this feels wrong.

Since there are multiple different implementations of Block, I cannot cast `src` to `ABlockImpl` before the call to `read`.

Is there an alternative way to "hide" `read`?

Comment: Please rephrase the title and question, it is misleading and I had to read it 3 times to get what you mean.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, I was thinking mostly about how to phrase it.

Comment: It sounds like you just want one class to implement two different interfaces, but I think you want an interface that is not public, am I right?

Comment: I am not sure. I think I want a public interface without `read` and a way for blocks to still `read` from each other.

Comment: I dont think you can or want to do this with an interface. Clients can provide their own implementations of Block, therefore `read()` has to be part of the interface. It sounds as if you want to provide all implementations yourself. I would therefore propose you publish an abstract class with a private `read()` or something.

Comment: I provided a possible solution as an answer

Comment: Is there anything that forbids an abstract class instead of an interface?

Comment: No, not that I can tell.

Comment: Then, you could define an abstract class, which implements none of the methods, but declares them with differen visibility. All subclasses of it would need to implement the methods, but `read` could stay hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a public interface and a package local one

```
public interface MyPublicInterface {

}

interface MyDirectInterface extends MyPublicInterface {

}

class MyImpl implements MyDirectInterface {

    public void add(MyPublicInterface mpi) {
         MyDirectInterface mdi = (MyDirectInterface) mpi;
         // use mdi
    }

}
```

Comment: When I change the type of `src` to `MyDirectInterface` I can no longer assign `src` in `connect(Block)`, since the caller gives me a public interface instance.

Comment: You have to cast the public interface to the private one on the assumption that all implementations of the public interface implement the private one. I have added an example.

Comment: In this case I would rather add `read` to the interface, do you agree?

Comment: You could document that the method is for internal use, if believe the developers will read it. You could give it a surprising name like `$read` or `read$`

Comment: Should I delete my question since there is no answer to it or what should I do?

Comment: If there wasn't an answer to your problem, I wouldn't have given one ;)

Comment: No, there is no correct answer. Even if you make the interface itself non-public, all methods a class has to implement because of this interface are public again. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801642/java-tutorial-says-i-can-have-a-package-private-interface-but-i-cant

Comment: @Sentry you cannot access a public method which is only exposed by an package local interface or class. (Except by using reflection in which case you can do almost anything)

Comment: @PeterLawrey True, but he didn't say that the implementation class is package local. It is in the code example, but I don't think this is part of the requirement. The moment the class itself is public, the method itself is accessible.

Comment: @Sentry True, but in his example and mine the class is package local.  I wouldn't say there is no correct answer, just because you have to do something specific to make it work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, but if the class _needs_ to be public, your solution wouldn't work anymore. I mean, it's better than what I came up with so far, but I think this should be pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You could create `abstract` layer between `interface` and concrete implementations of block and name it, for example, `BlockAdapter`.

I.e.:

```
interface Block {
    void connect(Block b);
    void step();
    double read();
}
```

...

```
public abstract class BlockAdapter implements Block { 
    double read() {
          return -1; // ? something like that
    }
}
```

...

```
public class ABlockImpl extends BlockAdapter { ... }
```

Comment: I thought the idea was to not have `read()` in the interface?

Comment: @JohannesSchad I think, that author possibly doesn't want it because in common case he must add this method implementation to all subclasses. `Adapter` pattern allows do it in only one layer and override this method in only desired subclasses.

Comment: No, I don't want to have `read` in the interface (if that is possible).

Comment: Why don't you remove `read` from the interface, but define it `protected` in the abstract class?

Comment: I defined it not `protected`, but `package local`. Indeed, may be it would be better to define it `protected`. I did that because author of the question said: *I need `read` only internally.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution that gives you exactly what you want, but maybe something close to it:

```java
interface Block {
    void connect(Block b);
    void step();
}
```

```java
interface ReadableBlock extends Block {
    double read();
}
```

The method `read()` still needs to be public, but you can let the exterior code only refer to implementations via the `Block` interface, while the implementation itself is from `ReadableBlock`

```java
public cass ABlockImpl implements ReadableBlock {
    ....
}
```

```java
Block b = new ABlockImpl();
```

Comment: I think this is very close to Peter Lawrey's solution.

Comment: Except that my interface are of same visibility and he didn't specify what the interfaces contain. But I have to admit, I only skimmed his answer ;)